# Send mails from Notes - when it is not used for mail

Tags: email, lotus-notes, lotusscript

Ok, in these times when some people move from Lotus Notes to Office 365 I have come across a certain requirement...

An older workflow application sends mail to users. This has worked fine for ages. But now we have a new type of users. These users are just using Notes for a couple of old legacy applications like the one in question.

The error we get is:

```
File does not exist
```

And the code that generates it is pretty simple:

```
Dim session As New NotesSession
Dim db As NotesDatabase
Dim rtitem As NotesRichtextItem
Dim doc2 As NotesDocument

Set db = session.CurrentDatabase
Set doc2 = New NotesDocument(db)
doc2.Form = "Memo"
doc2.Subject = "Test mail " & now
Set rtitem = New NotesRichTextItem (doc2, "Body" )      
Call rtitem.AppendText("A simple test....")
Call rtitem.addnewline(2)
Call rtitem.AppendText("Link to complaint ")
Call doc2.Replaceitemvalue("sendto", "john@dalsgaard-data.dk")
doc2.Send( False )
```

It fails when running the last line....

So, the question really is: How can I code around the this issue?

I know there is no mail file for the user - and I would really prefer not to have to create one for the new users.

Thanks in advance!

/John

Comment: Can't you just send it to the appropriate Office365 address for the same user?

Comment: Richard, the problem is not who I send to. The problem is that sending to ANY valid email address I get the error - if the Notes user sending the mail doesn't have a mail database (although set to mail system "Other")...

Comment: Do these users have the mail preferences option to save email messages when sending turned on?

Comment: Richard, they don't have Notes mail configured - so I can't really see any mail preferences...

Comment: Hmmm... I didn't think these preferences were in the profile within the mail file. I thought they were part of the client's general preferences. Bummer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have done some trial & error testing on this....

Conclusion so far is that it works in this situation:

In the LOCAL location document (in names.nsf on the computer) you specify:

1. Mail server - as a server the user can reach
2. Mail "On Server"
3. An existing mail file - it can be ANY existing file on the server, it doesn't have to be a mail database.

Actually, a non-conclusive test indicates the mail database even doesn't have to exist (but the user with the setup for testing had to leave - so I couldn't confirm this tonight...)

**Edit:**

Further testing indicates that this may not be a problem if the user is NOT roaming. I need some further verification that this is actually the reason why I got it working (for one thing you cannot remove the mail file name again once added)... But thought I would add it here.

Answer (score 1):

Error will appear when user triggering the code doesn't have a mail file specified in person document/location. One option would be to change code to save the new mail directly to server mail.box (assuming server is configured to route mails) or just send the email directly through SMTP using java.

Comment: Egor, that really isn't a good solution as that would require changing a lot of code - and would need a re-write of e.g. @-code that sends mail... - and on top of that it is an unsupported method to do exactly that - as far as I know.

Comment: Yes, depositing in mail.box is unsupported -- but it has been done by lots of people for years. As long as you set the minimum set of fields correctly, it works fine.

Comment: I know. But we would need to change all code that sends mails - I would rather prefer a configuration solution ;-)